# what is the maximum length of the record in a unix file?

Tags: shell, unix, limits

I am counting the file in unix by using `wc -l` here I have a doubt:

- if the exceeds the max length does it go to the second line?
- does it count second line as a record?

Here is the code I'm having issues with:

```
#!/bin/sh,for,line,in,$(cat,columns.txt),do,IFS='=,',read,-r,-a,array,<<<,$line,echo,"${array[0]}",echo,"${array[1]}",echo,"${array[2]}",echo,"${array[3]}",echo,`date,+%Y%m%d`,echo,"connecting,data,base,-,hive",db_name="dev_sri_open",ods="${array[0]}",country="${array[1]}",table="${array[2]}",columns="${array[3]}",export,db_name,export,ods,export,country,export,table,export,columns,hive,-hiveconf,database_name=$db_name,-hiveconf,run_date=`date,+%Y%m%d`,-hiveconf,table_name=$table,-hiveconf,country_name=$country,-hiveconf,order_date=$ods,,-hiveconf,column_names=$columns,-f,,'select.hql',>,/home/ecmappdev/extraction/${array[2]}.dat,done
```

It is very long, I can't explain why I want it on a single line anyway...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) example and [how to format your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) . Please edit your post to improved indentation.

Comment: what is that? Code? Please format code so that everyone can read and understand it and help u.

Comment: for line in $(cat columns.txt)
do
IFS='= ' read -r -a array <<< $line
echo "${array[0]}"
echo "${array[1]}"
echo "${array[2]}"
echo "${array[3]}"
echo "connecting data base - hive"
db_name=**
ods="${array[0]}"
country="${array[1]}"
table="${array[2]}"
columns="${array[3]}"
export db_name
export ods
export country
export table
export columns 
hive -hiveconf database_name=$db_name -hiveconf run_date=`date +%Y%m%d` -hiveconf table_name=$table -hiveconf country_name=$country -hiveconf order_date=$ods  -hiveconf column_names=$columns -f  'select.hql' > /*/*/${array[2]}.dat
done

Comment: we are generating a flat file from by using the script after that we are counting all records for example if one record exceeds the maximum length it comes to second line is this scenario is expected ?

Comment: @kotideveloper please edit the question, instead of adding comments. there is an "edit" button underneath your question

Comment: Answer is simple : there is no record in files from Unix point of view.

Comment: Please read [ask] before asking your next question.

Comment: UNIX utilities and C library functions have limits as documented in [opengroup limits.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/limits.h.html) . Run `getconf LINE_MAX` to see what the minimal supported line length is. Utilities can support longer than that if they wish.